# find the coefficient of the multivariate normal distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, determinant, multivalued-functions

We know that the multivariate normal distribution is given by $$f(x)=\frac 1 {c} e^{-\frac 1 2(x-\mu)^T\Sigma (x-\mu)}$$
Where $c =\sqrt {\det(\Sigma)2\pi}$

How do we derive this value for $c$?

EDIT: I understand that $c=\int e^{-\frac 1 2(x-\mu)^T\Sigma (x-\mu)dx}$ (which is a multivariable integral), but I don't know how to calculate that.

Comment: You derive it by normalising the density, if you are happy with the case where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix then try to consider the general case from a spectral decomposition of the covariance matrix and a corresponding change of variables in the integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it has to do with the Jacobian transformation of $X$, which correspond to the eigen value decomposition of $\Sigma$.

$\Sigma=Q\Lambda Q'$

$Q$ is orthogonal, and $\Lambda$ is diagonal. Then we also have

$Y=Q'X, Y\sim N(Q'\mu,\Lambda) $

$Y_i$ are mutually independent, and each has variance $\Lambda_{ii}$. So the constant in its pdf is $\sqrt{\prod{2\pi\Lambda_{ii}}}=\sqrt{(2\pi)^pdet(\Lambda)}=\sqrt{(2\pi)^pdet(\Sigma)}$

Answer (score 0):

The pdf for the Normal distribution is defined as:

## $$f(x)={1\over{\sqrt{2 \pi\sigma^2}}}e^{-(x-\mu)^2\over{2 \sigma^2}}$$

For the multivariate normal distribution instead of using a single value for variance, we are given a [Covariance Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) $\Sigma$, therefore in our case (where $\Sigma$ is assumed to be positive definite) we are looking to take the determinant of $\Sigma$ which will give us the generalized variance<sup>1</sup>.

I hope this insightful!

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>The generalized variance (GV) of a p-dimensional random vector variable X is de-
fined as the determinant of its variance-covariance matrix. GV was introduced by
Wilks  as a scalar measure of overall multidimensional scatter ([Source](http://faculty.ucr.edu/%7Eashis/publication/publications/ESS6053.PDF))</sub>

Comment: You are skipping over precisely the step that I don't understand, namely, how to derive that the determinant is equal to the integral of the exponent. Could you show that if you do this, you get the determinant? I don't really know how to "reduce $\Sigma $ to a single variable"

Comment: @Programmer2134 Sorry about my vague language. We are looking to find the generalized variance for a given multivariate normal distribution $f(x_1,....x_n)$ where $X_i \sim N(\mu_i,\sigma^{2}_i)$ The determinant is essentially the product of diagonal elements of  $\Sigma$ which would this give us a generalized variance of the distribution, think of $\sqrt{det(\Sigma)}$ in the multivariate normal distribution to  be synonymous with $\sqrt{\sigma^2}$ of the uni-variate normal distribution